# Extract specific string from URL

Tags: java, string, url, text-extraction

I want to extract some string from this url

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mtpdm/2019-06-14/12-14/1001_1203_20190614120605_5dd404.jpg

I want to extract the 2019-06-14, how do I do that using java?

Comment: what have you tried?  index of and substring? string split ?

Comment: I haven't tried, I just not sure on how to start it

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regular Expression to achieve this to get the **Date** `2019-06-14`,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractDateFromURL {

     public static void main(String []args) {
        String URL = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mtpdm/2019-06-14/12-14/1001_1203_20190614120605_5dd404.jpg";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{1,2})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Do what you need to do with the result
        }
     }
}
```

**Output**

> *2019-06-14*

And to get the `12-14` you can use the following Regular Expression,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractDateFromURL {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String URL = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mtpdm/2019-06-14/12-14/1001_1203_20190614120605_5dd404.jpg";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}|\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
     }
}
```

**Output**

> *12-14*